# Not showing column value

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I am using webhierarchicaldatagrid control of infragistics, In that I have 3 bands.

In lowest level band one of the column does not show up its value. When I do Inspect Element
I see as

```
<td val="Actual Value"></td>
```

But Other Columns which show there value properly are shown up as:

```
<td val="Actual Value">Actual Value</td>
```

I am not able to figure out why Infragistics is not putting "Actual Value" under  tag. I did not find anything about this issue on Infragistics forum. Please help guys, I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: This sounds like a bug and if you have a sample that reproduces this you should contact Infragistics support: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/388.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, I was using two columns which were holding hidden fields. When I introduced those two hidden fields somewhere in between other columns, It started showing up values of all the columns.